# onCreate() versus a database insert

Tags: android

My app has a high score activity. When the game activity ends it passes the game's state to the high score activity using Intent.putExtra()

The onCreate() pulls the game from extra and inserts the row into a database table.

This works fine... until I turned the device to landscape mode. onCreate() inserted the row into the high score table again.  Doh, I knew better than that, lol.

Ok, so what's the 'best practice' way of only allowing the row to be inserted once? I don't want to nuke the game data since I wish to display information about the game.

Ideas:
1. Add a flag to the extras and clear it once the row is inserted.  If the flag is clear, don't insert the row again.
2. Organize the database to throw a key violation failure on a dup insert.
3. copy the game out of extras, remove it from extras, and save/restore it in onPause() and onResume()

How would you handle the situation?

Comment: Have you considered overriding the `onConfigurationChanged()` method of your Activity in other for it not to re-create itself when the device is flipped? Could that be a viable solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a flag by doing something like this:

```
@Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putBoolean("high_score_saved", true);

        }

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    if (!savedInstanceSate.getBoolean("high_score_saved", false){
                        //save high score!

                     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add attribute android:configChanges="orientation" to your activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml. 
like

```
<activity android:name=".TestActivity" android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

This can be done if your activity doesn't change its layout when orientation changes. If you want to change layout on orientation change you can do like this by overriding this method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
      //your code
  } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
     //your code
  }
}
```